# What special rules does C++ apply to static const integral types?

Tags: c++, static, constants, standards

I was of the impression that C++ applies the same special rules to a `static const` integral type ***regardless*** of whether declared at namespace scope or declared within a class/struct/union.

Now I'm thinking that I've been taught Bad Things by non-compliant compilers.

```
static const int A = 1;

struct s
{
    static const int A = 1;
};
```

Aside from the obvious difference in scope, How do `A` and `s::A` differ?

- ...when their usage will be replaced with their literal value?
- ...when I can take the address of it?
- ...when I need to separately define them?

I'm curious specifically about C++ 03.

Comment: Why do you think there's a difference? The special treatment is that they can be considered constant expressions. Don't think in terms of "replacing with literal value".

Comment: @Pubby Try `const int &x = s::A;` after that, and use `x` somewhere. Chances are you'll get a linker error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword `static` doesn't mean the same thing in class scope
and in namespace scope.  In fact, it's use in namespace scope is
deprecated.

When declaring a variable at class scope, `static` means that
there will be one single instance of the variable, with static
storage duration and lifetime.  The declaration within the class
is *not* a definition; if the variable is *used*, it must be
defined in one (and only one) translation units; if it is not
defined, you have undefined behavior.  (In practice, depending
on the use, either everything will work fine, or you will get an
error from the linker.)  Note that if the declaration is for
a `const` integral type, and contains an initialization, it is
*not* considered used if it is used in a context which requires
a constant integral expression (like the dimension of a C style
array).  The simplest and surest thing is just to define it
somewhere.

When declaring a variable at namespace scope, `static` means
that the name has internal linkage, rather than external; with
or without `static`, the declaration is a definition (so there
should be no other definition in the program).  In C++03, this
use was deprecated; use unnamed namespace instead.  Note too
that if the variable itself is `const` (top level const), then
it has internal linkage by default, so the `static` has no
effect whatsoever.  (If you need a `const` variable with
external linkage, make it a class member, or define it
explicitly `extern`, using an initializer to make it
a definition, rather than just a declaration.)

Comment: It should be noted that static at namespace scope is no longer deprecated in C++11 so there is no need to avoid using it for the sake of future proofing.

Comment: @John5342 I thought I'd heard something along those lines.  Sounds a bit wishy-washy to me: deprecate, then undeprecate.  Next thing we know, they'll be restoring `export` and `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: It was deprecated because it has some odd side effects (i can't find the link at the moment) and unnamed namespaces offered a supposedly better alternative. There were then many complaints that unnamed namespaces did not provide an acceptable and complete alternative so it was undeprecated. Some would see it as wishy-washy. Others would call it listening to it's users and doing the right thing even if it means backtracking a little.

Comment: Export was never seriously implemented anyway (only one compiler to my knowledge) so it will never be just undeprecated. Besides, extern templates and the modules proposal (if it gets into the next standard) both help solve the same problem domain. std::auto_ptr does actually have a real, complete and improved replacement in the form of std::unique_ptr together with move semantics.

Answer (score 0):

> How do `A` and `s::A` differ?

The biggest difference is that the declaration of `A` is also a definition, while that of `s::A` is not.  I'm not sure what you mean by "special rules", but `static` has a different meaning in each case.

At namespace scope, it gives it *internal linkage* so that the object is not visible outside the current translation unit. Note that the `static` is redundant here, since constant variables at namespace scope have internal linkage by default.

At class scope, it means that there is a single object independent of any instantiation of the class.

> when their usage will be replaced with their literal value?

Since both are integral constants with an initialiser in the declaration, both can be used in constant expressions, and the compiler is able to replace their values with compile-time constants.

Perhaps a more appropriate question is, when is a definition required?

In C++11, it is required if the variable is *odr-used* - roughly speaking, if you do anything that requires the variable's address rather than its value.

In C++03, I think it was required if the variable is used at all, although no diagnostic is required and many compilers will not complain if you only use its value. I could be wrong though; the old rules were rather convoluted and I'm happy to be able to forget them now.

> when I can take the address of it?

That requires the variable to have a definition, in both C++03 and C++11. The definition allocates storage for the variable, so that it has an address.

> when I need to separately define them?

A variable declaration at namespace scope is also a definition, unless you declare it `extern`; so your first variable does not need a separate definition.

A variable declaration at class scope is not a definition; so your second variable does need a separate definition in C++03, and in C++11 if it is *odr-used*.